# Function aborts when inside manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I have a function that completes without problems, as shown here.

```
VisualizeRx[textimage, "test", 1, 0, 0, "WriteFiles" -> False];
```

But when it is inserted into a Manipulate, it aborts without completion.

```
Manipulate[
 VisualizeRx[textimage, "test", 1, 0, 0, "WriteFiles" -> False];
 , {{ds, 0, "DS"}, -4, 4, .25}
 , ContinuousAction -> False
 ]
```

[image]

The function `VisualizeRx` uses only local variables. The argument `textimage` refers to an image. It uses a lot of memory, but not more than available. Any ideas why the function won't work inside of manipulate?

Comment: add `SynchronousUpdating->False`

Comment: Thanks! That did it.